# Canvas rectangle which is filled with diagonal lines

Tags: javascript, canvas

I want to make the rectangle which is filled with diagonal lines.

So I made this code with `Gradient`.

However by this method, the edge between the color is blurred.

I want to get the diagonal line with clear edge.

Is there any good method to do this?

```js
<script>
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");


var ctx =  canvas.getContext( "2d" ) ;
ctx.beginPath () ;
ctx.rect( 50, 50, 80, 80 )

var lineargradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(50,50,130,130)

var num = 10
color = ["green","red"];
for (var i = 0 ; i < num;i++){ 
 lineargradient.addColorStop(i / num, color[i % 2]);
}
ctx.fillStyle = lineargradient;
ctx.fill() ;

ctx.strokeStyle = "purple" ;
ctx.lineWidth = 4 ;
ctx.stroke() ;


</script>
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas
```

Comment: Add both your colors at the same exact stop to get a clear cut

Comment: Thank you !!! it works well, I got completely clear edge.